# Ionic Capacitor iOS doesn't respect dark mode

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have an Ionic app using `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)`, when I build the ios version using capacitor, it does not respect dark mode. I have tried this [node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-dark-mode), [looked here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/dark-mode-not-working-capacitor/185400), [and here](https://enappd.com/blog/dark-mode-in-your-ionic-4-apps/105/), but nothing seems to work. Why does Capacitor not respect dark mode on iOS?

What is should look like.

[image]
[image]

Variables.css

```
    /* Ionic Variables and Theming. For more info, please see:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/ */

/** Ionic CSS Variables **/
:root {
  /** global font **/
  --ion-font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;

  /** primary **/
  --ion-color-primary: #3880ff;
  --ion-color-primary-rgb: 56, 128, 255;
  --ion-color-primary-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --ion-color-primary-shade: #3171e0;
  --ion-color-primary-tint: #4c8dff;

  /** secondary **/
  --ion-color-secondary: #3dc2ff;
  --ion-color-secondary-rgb: 61, 194, 255;
  --ion-color-secondary-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-secondary-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --ion-color-secondary-shade: #36abe0;
  --ion-color-secondary-tint: #50c8ff;

  /** tertiary **/
  --ion-color-tertiary: #5260ff;
  --ion-color-tertiary-rgb: 82, 96, 255;
  --ion-color-tertiary-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-tertiary-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --ion-color-tertiary-shade: #4854e0;
  --ion-color-tertiary-tint: #6370ff;

  /** success **/
  --ion-color-success: #2dd36f;
  --ion-color-success-rgb: 45, 211, 111;
  --ion-color-success-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-success-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --ion-color-success-shade: #28ba62;
  --ion-color-success-tint: #42d77d;

  /** warning **/
  --ion-color-warning: #ffc409;
  --ion-color-warning-rgb: 255, 196, 9;
  --ion-color-warning-contrast: #000000;
  --ion-color-warning-contrast-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --ion-color-warning-shade: #e0ac08;
  --ion-color-warning-tint: #ffca22;

  /** danger **/
  --ion-color-danger: #eb445a;
  --ion-color-danger-rgb: 235, 68, 90;
  --ion-color-danger-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-danger-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --ion-color-danger-shade: #cf3c4f;
  --ion-color-danger-tint: #ed576b;

  /** dark **/
  --ion-color-dark: #222428;
  --ion-color-dark-rgb: 34, 36, 40;
  --ion-color-dark-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-dark-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --ion-color-dark-shade: #1e2023;
  --ion-color-dark-tint: #383a3e;

  /** medium **/
  --ion-color-medium: #92949c;
  --ion-color-medium-rgb: 146, 148, 156;
  --ion-color-medium-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-medium-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --ion-color-medium-shade: #808289;
  --ion-color-medium-tint: #9d9fa6;
  --ion-color-medium-grey: #1e1e1e;

  /** light **/
  --ion-color-light: #f4f5f8;
  --ion-color-light-rgb: 244, 245, 248;
  --ion-color-light-contrast: #000000;
  --ion-color-light-contrast-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --ion-color-light-shade: #d7d8da;
  --ion-color-light-tint: #f5f6f9;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  /*
   * Dark Colors
   * -------------------------------------------
   */
  ion-menu {
    --ion-background-color: var(--ion-color-medium-grey);
    --ion-text-color: var(--ion-color-primary-contrast);
  }

  ion-toolbar {
    --background: var(--ion-color-medium-grey);
  }

  ion-list {/* optional, but it needs when you use gradient as a background color.*/
    background: #141414;
  }

  body {
    --ion-color-primary: #428cff;
    --ion-color-primary-rgb: 66,140,255;
    --ion-color-primary-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
    --ion-color-primary-shade: #3a7be0;
    --ion-color-primary-tint: #5598ff;

    --ion-color-secondary: #50c8ff;
    --ion-color-secondary-rgb: 80,200,255;
    --ion-color-secondary-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-secondary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
    --ion-color-secondary-shade: #46b0e0;
    --ion-color-secondary-tint: #62ceff;

    --ion-color-tertiary: #6a64ff;
    --ion-color-tertiary-rgb: 106,100,255;
    --ion-color-tertiary-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-tertiary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
    --ion-color-tertiary-shade: #5d58e0;
    --ion-color-tertiary-tint: #7974ff;

    --ion-color-success: #2fdf75;
    --ion-color-success-rgb: 47,223,117;
    --ion-color-success-contrast: #000000;
    --ion-color-success-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
    --ion-color-success-shade: #29c467;
    --ion-color-success-tint: #44e283;

    --ion-color-warning: #ffd534;
    --ion-color-warning-rgb: 255,213,52;
    --ion-color-warning-contrast: #000000;
    --ion-color-warning-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
    --ion-color-warning-shade: #e0bb2e;
    --ion-color-warning-tint: #ffd948;

    --ion-color-danger: #ff4961;
    --ion-color-danger-rgb: 255,73,97;
    --ion-color-danger-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-danger-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
    --ion-color-danger-shade: #e04055;
    --ion-color-danger-tint: #ff5b71;

    --ion-color-dark: #f4f5f8;
    --ion-color-dark-rgb: 244,245,248;
    --ion-color-dark-contrast: #000000;
    --ion-color-dark-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
    --ion-color-dark-shade: #d7d8da;
    --ion-color-dark-tint: #f5f6f9;

    --ion-color-medium: #989aa2;
    --ion-color-medium-rgb: 152,154,162;
    --ion-color-medium-contrast: #000000;
    --ion-color-medium-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
    --ion-color-medium-shade: #86888f;
    --ion-color-medium-tint: #a2a4ab;

    --ion-color-light: #222428;
    --ion-color-light-rgb: 34,36,40;
    --ion-color-light-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-light-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
    --ion-color-light-shade: #1e2023;
    --ion-color-light-tint: #383a3e;
  }

  /*
   * iOS Dark Theme
   * -------------------------------------------
   */

  .ios body {
    --ion-background-color: #141414;
    --ion-background-color-rgb: 20,20,20;

    --ion-text-color: #141414;
    --ion-text-color-rgb: 255,255,255;

    --ion-color-step-50: #0d0d0d;
    --ion-color-step-100: #1a1a1a;
    --ion-color-step-150: #262626;
    --ion-color-step-200: #333333;
    --ion-color-step-250: #404040;
    --ion-color-step-300: #4d4d4d;
    --ion-color-step-350: #595959;
    --ion-color-step-400: #666666;
    --ion-color-step-450: #737373;
    --ion-color-step-500: #808080;
    --ion-color-step-550: #8c8c8c;
    --ion-color-step-600: #999999;
    --ion-color-step-650: #a6a6a6;
    --ion-color-step-700: #b3b3b3;
    --ion-color-step-750: #bfbfbf;
    --ion-color-step-800: #cccccc;
    --ion-color-step-850: #d9d9d9;
    --ion-color-step-900: #e6e6e6;
    --ion-color-step-950: #f2f2f2;
  ;

    --ion-card-background: #1c1c1d;
  }

  .ios ion-modal {
    --ion-background-color: var(--ion-color-step-100);
    --ion-toolbar-background: var(--ion-color-step-150);
    --ion-toolbar-border-color: var(--ion-color-step-250);
  }


  /*
   * Material Design Dark Theme
   * -------------------------------------------
   */

  .md body {

    --ion-background-color: #141414;
    --ion-background-color-rgb: 20,20,20;

    --ion-text-color: #ffffff;
    --ion-text-color-rgb: 255,255,255;

    --ion-border-color: #222222;

    --ion-color-step-50: #1e1e1e;
    --ion-color-step-100: #2a2a2a;
    --ion-color-step-150: #363636;
    --ion-color-step-200: #414141;
    --ion-color-step-250: #4d4d4d;
    --ion-color-step-300: #595959;
    --ion-color-step-350: #656565;
    --ion-color-step-400: #717171;
    --ion-color-step-450: #7d7d7d;
    --ion-color-step-500: #898989;
    --ion-color-step-550: #949494;
    --ion-color-step-600: #a0a0a0;
    --ion-color-step-650: #acacac;
    --ion-color-step-700: #b8b8b8;
    --ion-color-step-750: #c4c4c4;
    --ion-color-step-800: #d0d0d0;
    --ion-color-step-850: #dbdbdb;
    --ion-color-step-900: #e7e7e7;
    --ion-color-step-950: #f3f3f3;

    --ion-item-background: #1e1e1e;

    --ion-toolbar-background: #141414;

    --ion-tab-bar-background: #1f1f1f;

    --ion-card-background: #1e1e1e;
  }


}
```

Comment: can you share your html of this page. i'll share my `variable.scss` file you can try using it.

Comment: try replacing your variable.scss with this file: https://github.com/Saqib92/ionic-dark-mode

Comment: Unfortunately didnt work once i deployed to xcode simulator @NajamUsSaqib

Comment: what simulator are you using? try updating your xcode and simulator to latest version and try again.

Comment: I am using the xcode similator. I will try to update everything and let you know

Comment: Are you on a M1 Mac? The iOS simulator has some problems with css files on M1 macs.

Comment: On a regular mac @jcesarmobile

Comment: Yes as @jcesarmobile said i faced some css issues on my M1 Mac. check again if you are in rosetta mode or something like this. Also try to build on real device to see the actual result. but still problem persist make Stackblitz or GitHub repo with minimum reproducible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a tricky one because the framework docs for Dark Mode aren't very clear and actually incorrect in some places. There is also a known bug with the dark mode logic they have in place too.

Basically, you need to add the CSS yourself to your `variables.scss` file at a class level.

If you add directly below your `@media` settings:

```
ion-card {
  --background: #141414;
}
```

That should change your card color. Apply the appropriate classes to each other element which isn't displaying in dark mode (i.e. your toolbar).

Answer (score 0):

I used @Najam Us Saqibs answer and re3moved the media query for his CSS solution of just using classes. The second problem was that the xcode emulator doesnt read the CSS correctly, and was misrepresenting how the app would look, which i confirmed by deploying it.